# Is there any difference in meaning between “doing something for 10 times” and “doing something 10 times”?

Tags: grammar

Help me please.I’m still trying to brush up my English.And does the word “for” change the meaning of the statements,just like “have been” and “has been”(note that “have been” and “has been” have nothing to do with the question but to give all of you an idea of any difference that might occur using the word “for”.

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this question to [ell.se] because it looks like an interesting learner's question despite not being accompanied by 'research'. The tags should also be updated post-migration (if the migration succeeds) - this question doesn't appear to be about [tag:grammar].

Answer (score 1):

*Doing something ten times* is correct / *Doing something for ten times* is not.  When you use [for + quantity] it means duration. For example *doing something for ten minutes*.

Comment: So does the addition of “for”change the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: 'For ten times' is just not a grammatical phrase in English. It doesn't change the meaning, it just makes the sentence wrong.

Comment: It doesn’t work as a prepositional phrase of time, but can work in sentences like this **For ten times the amount of an entry level model you can upgrade to the luxury edition**